# Round ImageView in Android

Tags: android, imageview, rounding

I am working on an Android application in which I am doing rounded image view. It is working fine with some images, but for the images like 160x120 resolution it shows an oval shaped.

My code for the custom imageview is given below:

```
public class RoundImage extends Drawable {
    private final Bitmap mBitmap;
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private final RectF mRectF;
    private final int mBitmapWidth;
    private final int mBitmapHeight;

    public RoundImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mBitmap = bitmap;
        mRectF = new RectF();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        final BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap,
        Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        mPaint.setShader(shader);

        mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
        mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawOval(mRectF, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);

        mRectF.set(bounds);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        if (mPaint.getAlpha() != alpha) {
            mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
            invalidateSelf();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        mPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
        return mBitmapWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
        return mBitmapHeight;
    }

    public void setAntiAlias(boolean aa) {
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(aa);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setFilterBitmap(boolean filter) {
        mPaint.setFilterBitmap(filter);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setDither(boolean dither) {
        mPaint.setDither(dither);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return mBitmap;
    }
}

// My main Activity Class

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView imageView1, imageView2;
    RoundImage roundedImage, roundedImage1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.tt);
        roundedImage = new RoundImage(bm);
        imageView1.setImageDrawable(roundedImage);
    }
}

// My xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/Brown"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView

Answer (score 1):

Add this gradle in your android project

```
compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
```

and added this line in your xml file (layout files)

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        app:civ_border_color="#EEEEEE"
        app:civ_border_width="4dp"
        app:civ_shadow="true"
        app:civ_shadow_radius="10"
        app:civ_shadow_color="#8BC34A"/>
```

In your java code

```
CircularImageView circularImageView = (CircularImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourCircularImageView);
// Set Border
circularImageView.setBorderColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.GrayLight));
circularImageView.setBorderWidth(10);
// Add Shadow with default param
circularImageView.addShadow();
// or with custom param
circularImageView.setShadowRadius(15);
circularImageView.setShadowColor(Color.RED);
```

[From here](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView)

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you please tell me how to call it in onCreate method?

Comment: that is lib first u added ad a lib project

Comment: I am unable to get R.styleable files

Comment: updatd my answer please check

Answer (score 0):

First of all use Picasso image loading library, for that you have to add one dependency like in build.gradle:

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

than create a seperate class called "CircleTransform" for displaying image into round shape and implements interface "Transformation"

than add following conde into it.

```
@Override
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
    int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

    int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
    int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

    Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
    if (squaredBitmap != source) {
        source.recycle();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(shader);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    float r = size/2f;
    canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

    squaredBitmap.recycle();
    return bitmap;
}

@Override
public String key() {
    return "circle";
}
```

After that you can set image into imageview like this :

```
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(R.drawable.tt)
                .transform(new CircleTransform())
                .into(imageView1);
```

That's it. i hope it helps.